# Early return from parent AND child method

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have a base class in ES6 like this:

```js
class BasePlot {
  props = {
    'data': []
  }

  constructor() { 
    // do things but don't setup data
  }

  draw(data){
    if (data && data.length )
      this.props.data = data;
    // Q: how to exit here if height and width are not yet available?
    this.setScale()
    this.setAxis()
  }

  setDimensions(height, width) {
    this.props.height = height;
    this.props.width = width;
  }
}
```

The class will never be instantiated directly but will be used only for inheritance.
Apart the constructor, all the other methods might be called in unpredictable order, that is why in the `draw` method I don't want to proceed if `height` and `width` are not yet defined for the instance.

I could simply add an `if` condition and exit but that's not what I had in mind.

In a child class I call the parent `draw` like this:

```js
class RectPlot extends BasePlot{ 
  draw(data){
    super.draw(data);
    // DON'T EXECUTE if height and width are not set
    // rest of the code
  }
}
```

In this case when I call the child `draw` I first call the parent method, and in case the `height` and `width`  are not set yet I'd like to exit (return) from the parent method but **ALSO** from the child one.

What I mean, is something like this:

```js
// Parent
draw(data){
  if (data && data.length )
    this.props.data = data;
    if(this.props.height && this.props.width)
      this.setScale()
      this.setAxis()
      return true
    }
    else return false
  }
}

// Child
draw(data){
  if(super.draw(data)){
    // proceed w rest of the code
  }
  else return false
}
```

This is exactly what I'd like to do, except I don't want to check with an `if` in all the subclasses if the parent `draw` completed successfully.

**Q:** Is there a way to 'early exit' a parent AND a child method besides the aforementioned repetition of the `if`-`else` block in all the children classes?

Comment: It's all visual, but perhaps if instead of using `if (blah) {..} else return false;`, you'd use `if (!blah) return false;` it would be a cleaner code...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return from a caller method from within a called method. However, you could avoid the problem altogether...

An alternative design could be to create another method, say `drawCanvas` for example, as follows...

```js
class BasePlot {
  props = {
    data: [],
  };

  draw(data) {
    if (data && data.length) this.props.data = data;
    if (this.props.height && this.props.width) this.drawCanvas(data);
  }

  drawCanvas(data) {
    this.setScale();
    this.setAxis();
  }
}

class RectPlot extends BasePlot {
  drawCanvas(data) {
    super.drawCanvas(data);
    // other stuff
  }
}
```

You would then override `drawCanvas` instead of `draw`, knowing that `drawCanvas` is only called if `width` and `height` exist.

I agree that checking the returned value of `super.draw(data)`, as in your example, is not ideal. It would be easy to forget this check, leading to potential errors. It is also not obvious to the reader of the child class implementation why this check is required without looking at the base class implementation.

Comment: I don't think this would help as I need to perform all the time the first step of the parent `draw`, that is to setup the data. Then the second step is optional depending on the height and width being already set or not. By following your logic then the parent `drawCanvas` should call the `draw` and we would be back to square one.

Comment: @Leonardo `drawCanvas` should not call `draw` because then it would recurse infinitely and crash. In the example above, the parent `drawCanvas` is called by the child `drawCanvas` which is called from the parent `draw` only if height and width are set. Hence, the first setup step is always performed by `draw` and the second step is optionally performed by `drawCanvas`, which meets your requirements.